# Disable ribbon panels resizing

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Is there a way to disable the resizing of panels when resizing the main window? I want to avoid Ribbon buttons to redraw in that kind of collapsed-view because they change their image/size. Not able to spot any functions in Ribbon/Category/Panel class for that.

See attached picture, when resizing the ribbon content resize too:

[image]

Comment: What is panel? Please attch a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Definition of ribbon panel here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/ribbon-designer-mfc?view=msvc-160)